# PostgresSQL - analyzing cpe23Uri

Tags: postgresql, split

I got a table like this, columns are text.

| cve | cpe23Uri |
| --- | --- |
| CVE-2019-0002 | `cpe:2.3:o:juniper:junos:15.1x53:d50:*:*:*:*:*:*` |

The fourth part(after the 3rd ":") is what I'm interested in - company name.

Is there a way that I can split/analyze the second column to find the top N companies with the most cve's?

I tried something with the "split_part" but I don't know how to do it for the whole table (second column).

Answer (score 1):

split_part can indeed be used for this:

```
select cve, 
       split_part(cpe23uri, ':', 4) as company_name
from the_table;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8ca96a147780bb72a5e2d4206da4fc2d)

Comment: Hey, now I'm getting an error even though the online example works fine for me.   I get "column cve_cpes.cpe23uri does not exist" for this qurey: "select cve, 
       split_part(public.cve_cpes.cpe23uri, ':', 4) as company_name
from public.cve_cpes;"